# How to add page number in footer using mpdf in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, mpdf

I'm using `niklasravnsborg/laravel-pdf` package in Laravel to generate a pdf. Now I want to add page number dynamically in footer part. Here is my code which I'm using correctly:

```
$config = ['instanceConfigurator' => function($mpdf) {
    $mpdf->SetWatermarkText('DRAFT');
    $mpdf->showWatermarkText = true;
}];

return PDFm::loadHtml($space.$result->document, $config)->download('draftAgreement.pdf');
```

Answer (score 2):

You could configure your `mpdf` instance to include page numbers.

```
$config = ['instanceConfigurator' => function($mpdf) {
    $mpdf->SetWatermarkText('DRAFT');
    $mpdf->showWatermarkText = true;
    $mpdf->setFooter('{PAGENO}');
}];

return PDFm::loadHtml($space.$result->document, $config)->download('draftAgreement.pdf');
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer bro, your solutions is working but there is one problem. In footer one line is coming so how can i remove that.

Comment: I am not entirely sure what you mean. Page numbers are added to a footer. You can look at the [Headers & Footers](https://mpdf.github.io/headers-footers/headers-footers.html) documentation for more information.